# Why is the para product major in the nitrosation of phenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, phenols

When phenol reacts with nitrous acid ($\ce{NaNO2 + \mathrm{conc}\ H2SO4}$), 4-nitrosophenol and not 2-nitrosophenol is formed. I cannot understand why the *para*-isomer should be preferred over the *ortho*-isomer.

I understand the reaction mechanism proceeds by electrophilic substitution by the $\ce{NO+}$ cation, and that the $\ce{OH}$ group activates the ring, which leads to *ortho* and *para* substitution.

I don't understand why the *para*-isomer should be preferred over *ortho*?

Answer (score 9):

Ortho and para positions are activated due to the +R effect of the $\ce{-OH}$ but the preference of the para product can be explained by the mechanism.

> [image]

The mechanism proceeds through a dienone. The ortho dienone intermediate will experience strain as  $\ce{=O}$ annd$\ce{=NOH}$ lie in the same plane. Para nitrosated intermediate on the other hand is free from strain.

---

**Reference:** González-Mancebo S., Lacadena J., García-Alonso Y., Hernández-Benito J., Calle E., Casado J. *Monatsh. Chem.* **2002**, *133* (2), 157-166. [DOI: 10.1007/s706-002-8245-0](https://doi.org/10.1007/s706-002-8245-0).

Comment: I feel this answer would be improved a lot by a drawing of the strained *ortho*-intermediate.

Answer (score -2):

Due to steric hinderance and also there is some electronegativity of alcohol group due to induction it takes electron from sigma bond though not dominating therefore

These are the 2 reasons for more p- substitution

Comment: Sources, please.